# Is there any difference between using '=' in a 'join' or 'where' on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-5, where-clause

I have used both ways:

```
$this->data = DB::table('projects')
     ->select('companies_info.*', 'project_roles_types.name AS project_role_name')
     ->join('project_companies_members', 'project_companies_members.project_id', 'projects.project_id')
     ->where($some_variable, $project_id)
     ->get();
```

and:

```
$this->data = DB::table('projects')
    ->select('companies_info.*', 'project_roles_types.name AS project_role_name')
    ->join('project_companies_members', 'project_companies_members.project_id', '=', 'projects.project_id')
    ->where($some_variable, '=', $project_id)
    ->get();
```

and for me it has worked the same either adding or removing the `=` sign.
Does anybody know if this is allowed? If so, what's the best way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the function definition in the source:

```
// Here we will make some assumptions about the operator. If only 2 values are
// passed to the method, we will assume that the operator is an equals sign
// and keep going. Otherwise, we'll require the operator to be passed in.
```

So you can see, if you omit the `=` as the second argument, the query builder will place it there by default, which is consistent with the behavior you describe.

[Reference](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php#L497)

Answer (score 4):

This is fine, the '=' is the default operator in the query builder.

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L497 for source of the 'where' code. It assumes that if 2 arguments exist, it is the equals operator.